# jquery: bind onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, bind

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a#fav').bind('click', addFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>));
});
```

was before

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a#fav').bind('click', addFav);
});
```

I added `(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>)` because i want the user profile´s id to work with in the addFav ajax call.

So i have this at the bottom of my page and now even if i havnt clicked on the a#fav it runs it? But it doesnt run itself when i dont have the (id)

Heres addFav in case:

```
function addFav(id){
    $.ajax({
      url: "misc/favAdd.php",
      data: { id: id},
      success: function(){
           $('a#fav')
                 .addClass('active')
                 .attr('title','[-] Remove as favorite')
                 .unbind('click')
                 .bind('click', removeFav(id))
           ;
                jGrowlTheme('wallPop', 'mono', '[+] Favorit', 'Du har nu lagt till denna profil som favorit', 'images/addFavorit_hover2.png', 1000);
      }
    });
}

function removeFav(id){
    $.ajax({
      url: "misc/favRemove.php",
      data: { id: id },
      success: function(){
            $('a#fav')
                 .removeClass('active')
                 .attr('title','[+] Add as favorite')
                 .unbind('click')
                 .bind('click', addFav(id))
            ;
                            jGrowlTheme('wallPop', 'mono', '[-] Favorit', 'Du har nu tagit bort denna profil som favorit', 'images/addFavorit_hover2.png', 1000);
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter to the `bind` function is a function itself.  When you pass a function as a parameter, you must only supply the function name, not the opening/closing parenthesis or arguments.

In your case, if you'd like to pass parameters to the `addFav` function, you may do so by passing an anonymous function to `bind`, and within the body of that function, call `addFav` as you normally would with your parameters. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a#fav').bind('click', function() {
        addFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need an anoymous function like this onload:

```
$(function() {    
  $('a#fav').click(function(
    addFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>)
  });
});
```

And this style in your `success` callbacks:

```
$('#fav').click(function() {
  addFav(id);
});
```

since `#fav` should be a unique ID, it's a much faster selector.

---

Or, pass it as the data argument to [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), like this:

```
$('a#fav').bind('click', { id: id }, addFav);
```

And in your function access it that way instead of as a parameter, like this:

```
function addFav(e){
  var id = e.data.id;
```