# jQuery: it addclass, remove class itself?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a#fav').bind('click', function() {
        addFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>);
    });
});


function addFav(id){
    $.ajax({
      url: "misc/favAdd.php",
      data: { id: id},
      success: function(){
           $('a#fav')
                 .addClass('active')
                 .attr('title','[-] Remove as favorite')
                 .unbind('click')
                 .bind('click', removeFav(id))
           ;
                jGrowlTheme('wallPop', 'mono', '[+] Favorit', 'Du har nu lagt till denna profil som favorit', 'images/addFavorit_hover2.png', 1000);
      }
    });
}

function removeFav(id){
    $.ajax({
      url: "misc/favRemove.php",
      data: { id: id },
      success: function(){
            $('a#fav')
                 .removeClass('active')
                 .attr('title','[+] Add as favorite')
                 .unbind('click')
                 .bind('click', addFav(id))
            ;
                            jGrowlTheme('wallPop', 'mono', '[-] Favorit', 'Du har nu tagit bort denna profil som favorit', 'images/addFavorit_hover2.png', 1000);
      }
    });
}
```

I have this issue, that when i click on a#fav then it addClass active, and removes it and add and remove and send a bunch of ajax itself.. it goes crazy. 
And i do not want that, i want to have it so when you click a#fav it adds class (send ajax call) and then when you click it again it sends ajax call and removes the class. And it goes on like that..

What have i done wrong?

Comment: are you even reading the answers to your question?  I [answered this specifically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646162/jquery-bind-onclick/3646168#3646168) in your last question.  It's quicker to read answers you *already* have than asking another duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing `.bind('click', removeFav(id))`, you are calling `removeFav` *immediately* and passing its return value to the `bind` function.

Instead, you need to pass a function that calls `removeFav`, like this:

```
             .bind('click', function() { removeFav(id); })
```

(And similarly for `addFav` later)

Comment: `.bind('click', removeFav(id)` looks wrong, needs to be wrapped in anonymous, +1